# How to select a blender rig control using python script?

Tags: scripting, rigging

I have a rig in Blender, and I want to write a script that selects any one rig control. But I am unable to select the the control. What I am basically doing is copying the python instructions on the top panel and repeat them in the script editor.

Here is the code I have so far :

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

bpy.context.space_data.context = 'DATA'
bpy.context.object.active_index = 0
bpy.ops.pose.group_select()
```

First 2 lines work fine, then I am going to data tab and selecting a bone group. Here I get the error : `SpaceTextEditor has no attribute 'context'`

I'm sure this is some silly error but I'm an absolute beginner so any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to select a bone in pose mode?

Comment: `bpy.context.space_data.context = 'DATA'` is setting the properties window to display data panels, eg mesh for mesh, bones for armature object.  Could prob just ditch it.  Then you'll get "context.object" has no "active_index" prop, do you mean "active_shape_key_index" perhaps.

Comment: @ Leander - yes, I am trying to select the bone, i guess.